# jQuery toggle class and content on click of link

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

The following code is working exactly as it is expected to work, the thing is that I'm sure that it can be written in a more efficient and less verbose way, any reviews?

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hidden-content').hide();
    $(".hidden-content-reveal").click(function() {
        var $i = $(this).children();
        if ($i.is(".angle-down")){
            $i.removeClass("angle-down");
            $i.addClass("angle-up");
        } else {
            $i.removeClass("angle-up");
            $i.addClass("angle-down");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <a href="#" class="hidden-content-reveal">
        <i class="angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="hidden-content">
        <p>Nulla facilisi. Cras non egestas lectus. Duis malesuada eleifend neque, eget tincidunt elit convallis sed.Nulla facilisi. Cras non egestas lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.toggleClass()` for example? http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: @MarioSantini `.toggleClass()`  is working, but the "trick" is that I had to target both classes like that: `toggleClass("angle-down angle-up")`. Post your comment as an answer so to be able to accept it.

Comment: I believe this is your first post, could you add a summary of what your code does to your post.

Comment: Does exactly that @Tushar has written to the below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('.hidden-content').hide();` can be moved to CSS. This will be better UX and user will not see any flickr on the screen if page take long time to load and thus hide the element by JavaScript.

```
.hidden-content {
    display: none;
}
```

To check if an element have a class, [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) can be used instead of `is()`.

The methods can be chained `$i.removeClass("angle-down").addClass("angle-up");` but there is better way to do this.

To toggle the class on an element, [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) can be used. This also accepts callback function.

```
$('selector').toggleClass(function() {
    return $(this).children().hasClass('angle-down') ? 'angle-up' : 'angle-down';
});
```

`toggleClass` also accepts list of classes separated by space. If the element have already applied one of the class from it, `toggleClass` will remove it and add other classes. Now, the code will become,

```
$('selector').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
```

**Demo:**

Note that in Demo, I've added Font-Awesome to demonstrate the functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hidden-content-reveal").click(function() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');

    $(this).next('.hidden-content').slideToggle();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <a href="#" class="hidden-content-reveal">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="hidden-content">
    <p>Nulla facilisi. Cras non egestas lectus. Duis malesuada eleifend neque, eget tincidunt elit convallis sed.Nulla facilisi. Cras non egestas lectus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```